# Removing selected characters from text file

Tags: python

I have long a text file where each line looks something like `/MM0001 (Table(12,))` or `/MM0015 (Table(11,))`. I want to keep only the four-digit number next to `/MM`. If it weren't for the "table(12,)" part I could just strip all the non-numeric characters, but I don't know how to extract the four-digit numbers only. Any advice on getting started?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's exactly that format, you could just print out `line[3:7]`

Answer (score 2):

You could parse text line by line and then use 4th to 7th char of every line. 
ln[3:7]

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
R=re.compile(r'/MM(\d+)')
for line in file:
    L=R.match(line)
    if L:
       print L.group(1)
```

or, more succinctly...

```
lines=[R.match(line).group(1) for line in file]  #works if the lines are guaranteed to start with \MM
```

This should give you only the integers following a `/MM` and should work no matter how long the strings of integers are.  If they're guaranteed to be a certain length, then you're better off with one of the other examples (which don't use regex).

Answer (score 0):

if each line starts with `/MM` then just go through the file and print out `line[3:7]` e.g.

```
for line in file:
    print line[3:7]
```